# Dist folder is not getting created while building a single-spa root node app

Tags: node.js, deployment, build, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I developed a micro-front end UI app, the application is running on local by `npm start` command, but now I want to deploy it, for that I need to publish it using build command, when I am trying to run `npm build --prod` or just `npm build`, its not throwing any error but I don't see any dist folder created in my app root folder.
Below is my package.json and app structure:

```
{
  "name": "root-html-file",
  "description": "The single-spa root config for coexisting-angular-microfrontends",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "serve -s -l 4200",
  },
  "author": "Joel Denning",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "serve": "^11.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Dist folder is not getting created while building a single-spa root node app

When we build the app on the azure cloud server, Azure devops will checkout the source code from the repo to the build agent. Then the output of the build pipeline will save on this agent instead of our repo.

So, we could not see the `dist` folder from the repo. It is saved in the local folder on the agent. We need use the [copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [publish build artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to  publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines.

[image]

Note: The `Source Folder` in the copy files task should be `Agent.BuildDirectory` or `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` instead of directly selecting the path in the repo through the extension button.

If above not help you, please share you build log, so that we could check if the dist folder created or not.

Comment: That is ok, but its not creating the `dist` folder even on my local machine, when I run `build` command

Comment: @AshokDamani, If its not creating the dist folder even on your local machine, when you run `build` command, this issue should not related to the Azure devops, more related to `npm build` and single-spa node app, you could change the tag to get better attention.